# How to check if all values in an array are the same mongodb aggregation?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

How to check if all values in an array are the same mongodb aggregation? Say I have an array `["a","a","a","a","a"]` in an aggregation stage. How do I check if all the values are the same using mongodb aggregation?

And if there is a different approach for an array of objects `[{a:"a",b:"b"},{a:"c",b:"d"}]`. How do I check if all the values of a given object property are the same for all objects in an array using mongodb aggregation?

I know in javascript I can use `array.every()` is there an equivalent in mongodb?

Comment: What about `{$eq:[{$size: { $setUnion: <expression> }, 1]}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            areSame: {
                $allElementsTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$key",
                        in: {
                            $eq: [ "$$this", { $arrayElemAt: [ "$key", 0 ] } ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AN4xPolonL9)

same solution should work for [objects](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z9cI5tjsE37)